# awk simple printf syntax

Tags: command-line, awk

I am practicing printf functions with awk command.

```
echo "unix" | awk '{printf "%5s\n", "hi"}'
awk '{printf "%20s\n", "hi"}'
```

The first command with echo prints "   hi". 
However, the second command causing a problem. 
Its output keeps continuing. How do I fix this problem so that it does exactly what the first command does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` loops on each record of input. If no input files are specified, it uses standard input. If you want to run an expression without using any input, use a `BEGIN` block, and keep nothing outside it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "foo"}'
foo
```

So, in your case:

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%20s\n", "hi"}'
```

Usually, the `BEGIN` block is run before any input is read. So, it is run whether or not there is any input, and since there are no other expressions to run, `awk` simply exits.

You can also use `exit` to make awk exit the loop:

```
awk '{printf "%20s\n", "hi"; exit}'
```